# How to read and write certain columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlsx file, that has 5 columns filled with numbers.

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

If I write

```
amount = df.shape[0]
col = df.shape[1]

a= np.array([[0]*amount]*col)

for i in range(amount):
    a[0][i] = df[1][i]
```

It will display first column, but if I write

```
for j in range(col):
for i in range(amount):
    a[j][i] = df[j][i]
```

Or simply `df[2][i]`  it sends me an error

How can I refer to a certain column? The 'test.xlsx' file have `item1, item2, item3, item4, item5` in its first row

Comment: Two thoughts/questions:
1 - your line for `a = ...`, what is that `[0]` supposed to be doing? It looks like it is just the list containing one item, which has the value of zero, and multiplying that by stuff, is that right?
2 - in your last code-block, if you are trying to do a sort of double-loop, your indentation right now is failing on that. You need the `for i...` line indented, and then the `a[j][i]...` line indented another layer.

That said, what exactly are you trying to get to? If you are trying to have a new column that is a function of other columns, there are easier ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to display columns with a for loop over new numpy matrix? You already have your dataframe df which you can use to access what you need.

You can refer to columns by name or by index.
If you want to access all rows of your first column you can use index locator:

```
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Or referring to it by a name (let's say 'col1'):

```
df.loc[:, 'col1']
# or 
df['col1']
```

If you really need this in the form of a numpy array you can write:

```
df['col1'].to_numpy()
# or the whole dataframe
df.to_numpy()
# which gives a raw 2d array
```

`df[2][i]` throws an error likely because you dont have a column named `2` in your df.
Accessing via `df[i][j]` - `i` needs to be the column name (not index) and `j` needs to be the row index. To access items purely by index use `df.iloc`.

If you want to display your first row `item1, item2, item3, item4, item5` you can write `df.iloc[0, :]`

Two other points:

1. To create an empty array you can use

```
np.zeros([5,5]) # 5 rows 5 cols
```

2. Your double for loop needs to be indented:

```
for j in array1:
    for i in array2:
        print(i, j)
```